# Manage Transactions on Business Layer

Tags: enterprise-library, transactionscope

I want to use **TransactionScope** class in my business layer to manage database operation in data access layer.

Here is my sample code. When i execute it, it tries to enable the dtc. I want to do the operation without enable dtc.

I already checked https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/32592 article. It didn't work for me. I read many articles on this subject but none of them really touch enterprise library or i didn't see.

by the way, i am able to use TransactionScope using dotnet sql client and it works pretty well.

what would be the inside of SampleInsert() method?

Thanks,

**Business Layer method:**

```
public void SampleInsert()
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                Sample1DAL dal1 = new Sample1DAL(null);
                Sample2DAL dal2 = new Sample2DAL(null);
                Sample3DAL dal3 = new Sample3DAL(null);
                dal1.SampleInsert();
                dal2.SampleInsert();
                dal3.SampleInsert();
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
```

**Data Access Layer method:**

```
//sampleInsert method structurally same for each 3 dal

public void SampleInsert()
        {
            Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(Utility.DATABASE_INFO); ;
            using (DbConnection conn = database.CreateConnection())
            {
                conn.Open();
                DbCommand cmd = database.GetStoredProcCommand("P_TEST_INS", "some value3");
                database.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi yes this will enable dtc because you are creating 3 DB connections within one TransactionScope . When more than one DB connection is created within same TransactionScope the local transaction escalate to Distributed Transaction and hence dtc will be enabled to manage Distributed Trnsactions.You will have to do it in a way that only one DB connection is created for entire TransactionScope. I hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks, that was the actual reason.

Answer (score 0):

After research and waching query analyzer, I changed the SampleInsert() body as follows and it worked. The problem was as **ethicallogics** mentioned opening new connection each time i access the database.

```
public void SampleInsert()
        {
            Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(Utility.DATABASE_INFO);
            using (DbCommand cmd = database.GetStoredProcCommand("P_TEST_INS", "some value1"))
            {
                database.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
            }
        }
```